# Use mapped shortcut without timeout

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, vimscript

I have these in my .vimrc:

```
set notimeout
nnoremap <leader>n :set rnu!<CR>
nnoremap <leader>h :<C-u>call Toggle_colorcolumn()<CR>
```

`<leader>n` works instantly; `<leader>h` waits until I press Return or Escape key. Why does vim wait? I want it to take effect immediately.

This is the function definition just in case the problem is there:

```
function Toggle_colorcolumn()
    if &colorcolumn != 80
        exec('set colorcolumn=80')
    else
        exec('set colorcolumn=0')
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Just FYI, your code can just use `set colorcolumn=80` directly. It’s an ex command.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks both for the tip and welcoming me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had another binding that `<leader>h` was a prefix and I had forgotten about; it was `<leader>html`. Removing it solved the problem.